# For a method like fillOval what does 'x' and 'y' denote ? What coordinates are they?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

For a method of `Graphics` class: [fillOval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), what does `x` and `y` denote ? The documentation says:

```
x - the x coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
y - the y coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
```

I do not understand this. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
x - the x coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
y - the y coordinate of the upper left corner of the oval to be filled.
```

See the image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On a piece of paper, draw a rectangle. Then draw an oval inside the rectangle, filling up the rectangle as much as possible (the oval should touch all 4 sides of the rectangle once).

The top-left corner *of the square* is (x,y)

Comment: In this [picture](http://i46.tinypic.com/iz934p.jpg),all the 9 buttons have been drawn while keeping the `x,y as (0,0)`. What does that mean?

Comment: @saplingPro Perhaps there was a [*transformation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) between drawing the circles? If they were truly draw at the same coordinates, then there would only appear to be one circle.

Comment: _Perhaps there was a transformation between drawing the circles_..I didn't understand this

Comment: @saplingPro I added a link. If there are still questions of how all the buttons can be drawn at the "same coordinates" (i.e. `(0,0)`), add a link showing *the code that renders it like this* to the main question and add this (sub) question to the main question as well - I suspect that a transformation is being applied.

Comment: Let me tell you , I first used IDE to place buttons,then those buttons shape was changed as `JButton b = new RoundButton()`. The roundbutton class has all the code that makes the button..So is this what you call transformation ?

Comment: Well, it is a sort of a transformation, but a different kind. When the button draws itself it draws to a graphics object with it's *own* coordinate system. So when the circle is drawn at `(0,0)`, that is relative to it's own graphics object (think of a square "drawing area" behind each circle that entirely contains each circle), but not the entire screen. This is how a control can render it's contents the same, even as the control is moved across the screen - the local coordinate system does not change.

Comment: @saplingPro: you determnix `x` and `y` according to the object which you will draw on it , you create button , this button have `x` and `y` , so when you draw the ovell on it you will be relative to  the object(button)